# Android build a jsonarray of jsonobjects

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'd like to build a json object which contains, among others, an array of objects like this:

```
{"ChoisiEvents":[{"Id_evt":25},{"Id_evt":4}],"parasite":3}
```

I have written some code like :

```
JSONArray JAChoisiEvents = new JSONArray();
JSONObject objEvent = new JSONObject();
try{
    if (cbxTemp.isChecked()){
          objEvent.put("Id_evt", 25);
          JAChoisiEvents.put(objEvent);
    }
    if (cbxAutreRaison.isChecked()) {
          objEvent.put("Id_evt", 4);
          JAChoisiEvents.put(objEvent);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
//...
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 try {
   obj.put("parasite", iParasite); 
   System.out.println("ChoisiEvents : " + JAChoisiEvents.toString());
   obj.put("ChoisiEvents", JAChoisiEvents); //
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I got the following result:

```
{"ChoisiEvents":[{"Id_evt":4},{"Id_evt":4}],"parasite":3}
```

As you can see, the last item in my array is repeated each time !

Comment: Adding `"Id_evt", 25` in JSONArray and getting `{"Id_evt":6}` in result ?

Comment: sorry, I correct my code (that's an extract).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same JSONObject, thats why value is overriding,

try to instantiate for the second time

```
objEvent = new JSONObject();
```

After adding to the first value.

Like this

```
JSONObject objEvent;

    if (cbxTemp.isChecked()){
         objEvent = new JSONObject();
          objEvent.put("Id_evt", 25);
          JAChoisiEvents.put(objEvent);
    }
    if (cbxAutreRaison.isChecked()) {
         objEvent = new JSONObject();
          objEvent.put("Id_evt", 4);
          JAChoisiEvents.put(objEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Great, You've got the solution ! Thanks